# Application that uses another for authentication - anyway to circumvent using their login page?

Tags: spring-security, web-applications, oauth, oauth-1.0a

I'm writing an application (AppA) that relies on another application (AppB) to verify authentication (since ultimately AppA runs utilities against AppB - and is used by users of AppB).

AppB implements OAuth 1.0a. We can use OAuth to authenticate against it by re-directing users of our app to the AppB login screen, and once they login they are returned to our application.

However, if possible it would be good to present our own login interface instead of using AppB's. Is there anyway to do this safely? I know we can intercept their credentials and pass it to AppB in the background and login for them, but this seems frowned upon, and wondering if there is any way or mechanism to do this safely? Or is this something we should not do at any cost and the login redirect is the only real method with OAuth 1.0a?

Thank you,

Comment: If you are the First-party (Which means that they trust you that your application would not misuse the credentials) and the users of your app trust you with their credentials then you can do it. For e.g. some app opens a screen and asks for Facebook credentials then it would be frowned upon. But if the Facebook app opened the login screen then users would happily enter their credentials

Comment: Thank you! This will be the case. The other option was looking at was directing them to the applications login page, but thinking that will negatively impact the user experience was going for. Not in a drastic way, but would prefer to have them only login via our login form if possible. But wasn't sure if we would be violating any principles or practices if we did it this way (and if there was a way we could do it securely)